# What to do with non-responsive lxpanel?

Tags: lubuntu, lxpanel

My Lubuntu 18.04's lxpanel doesn't respond. For example the clock shown in the panel is stuck.

The following doesn't seem to work:

```
$ killall lxpanel 

$ ps aux | grep lxpanel
t         8681  0.0  0.0  21544   996 pts/4    S+   20:14   0:00 grep --color=auto lxpanel
t        21804  0.1  0.9 878668 74040 ?        D    Mar16 109:25 lxpanel --profile Lubuntu
```

What shall I do?

Thanks.

Comment: `lxpanelctl restart`?

Comment: @guiverc  Lubuntu 18.04

Comment: @OrganicMarble not working